# Firebird install conflict with Interbase

Tags: firebird, interbase

Are there conflicts created if Firebird is installed to a system that already has Interbase installed. I see some mention of using the same Ports, additions to the Path, and a common program name in ISQL.exe as the command processor.  I see references to FB version 1.5 documentation to resolve these, is there more updated information? Has this not been changed in current releases? If Firebird (current version) is simply installed, will Interbase installations then have problems and need work to get them working again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.You need to modify the port section for firebird in the conf so each will have a different port

2.when you asked about if to copy the legacy gds32 dll you need to uncheck it for firebird install setup so it will install only in it's own folder and not on the system

http://ibexpert.net/ibe/uploads/Doc/dmiles469.gif

The ISQL.exe issue can be solved in command line with modified PATH so you can add there the Firebird install path

Comment: has this been the same for all versions 1.5-2.5? Is there a reason they keep these things the same as Interbase?

Comment: There are millions of Delphi applications that were coded with gds32 dll but if you use a modern Firebird 2.5 it shouldn't create any issues because it creates a fbclient.dll and only if you check that checkbox at install it will create a legacy gds32.dll (by default it shouldn't)